# First deployment, ASP.net image buttons not showing when page is first loaded

Tags: asp.net, deployment, controls, imagebutton

I finally got my site to work on my server, and it is now visible at http://www.mhn.co but when you click on any of the categories on the top it loads a professional's profile, but the image buttons I'm using like tabs on the profile content don't load, and just display "Submit Query" until clicked on, then the images load. This is my first asp.net site that I've deployed so I'm pretty unfamiliar with how this should work. The server is running asp.net 2.0, 3.0, and 3.5, and my site is using 2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you assigning image on load ? Cause the src is null or empty at first. And on the click
you probably added the image on postback or something.

```
before click :
   src = "";

after click
   src = "./css/img/content_tab_profile_rollover.jpg"
```

Try adding image on the load

Comment: I changed it and am re-uploading now. This worked fine on my local machine, should I expect more discrepancies like this one?

Comment: If you add image dynamically, you have to check for this kind of behaviour. You have to put all your images, strings on the load event.
Also if you don't want your image to appear invisible, pre-load them.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a problem with the server. It's a problem with the markup or control you're using. Because if you look at the image URL it's trying to use when it first loads it's "http://www.mhn.co/profile.aspx?name=Mounir". But then when you click it works because it points to "http://www.mhn.co/css/img/content_tab_profile_rollover.jpg".

Without seeing your code/markup we can't really do much more. But that is where I'd look